# JavaScript addEventListener

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

He Stackoverflow,

Question is simple,
If the window size is smaller than width 960px i can click a menu button.
When i click it the nav height will be 325px instead of 60px and thats what i wanted to happen. It works but, you only can see the result if you click the button for the second time. Can someone explain why this happens?

```js
// GET DOM

var getdom = (function(){
    
    var DOMstrings = {
        menuBtn: '#menu',
        navToggle: 'nav',
    }
    
    return {
        getDOMstrings: function(){
            return {
                menu: document.querySelector(DOMstrings.menuBtn),
                nav: document.querySelector(DOMstrings.navToggle),
            }
        }
    }
    
    
})();

// Global Controllor

var global = (function(dom){
    
    var get = dom.getDOMstrings();
    
    
    function start(){        
        // MENU NAV HEIGHT
        get.menu.addEventListener('click', function(){
            console.log('click!');
            
            if(get.nav.style.height === '60px'){
                get.nav.style.height = '325px';
            }else {
                get.nav.style.height = '60px';
            }
            
        });
        
        
        
        
    }
    
    
    return {
        init: function(){
            start();
        }
    }
    
})(getdom);

global.init();
```

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: gray;
}

nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: all 1s;
}

#brand {
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 32px;
    left: 10px;
    top: 8px;
}

#menu {
    position: absolute;
    left: 140px;
    top: 20px;
    display: none; 
    cursor: pointer;
}


nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-top: 15px;
}

nav ul li {
    display: inline;
    font-size: 22px;
}

nav ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: darkslategray;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    padding: 10px 11px;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}

.nav-link:hover {
    font-size: 24px;
}

#dropdown {
    padding-left: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 965px) {
    nav {
        height: 325px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
    nav ul li {
        display: block;
        border-bottom: 1px solid black;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
        padding-top: 10px;
        margin-left: -10%;
    }
    
    .margintop {
        margin-top: 50px;
    }
    
    nav ul li a {
        border-right: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
    }
    
    #dropdown {
        padding-left: 0px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 959px){
    nav {
        height: 60px;
    }
    
    #menu {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <title>Website</title>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
    <nav>
       
       <div id="brand">BRAND</div>
       <div id="menu">MENU</div>
        <ul>
            <li class="margintop"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class='nav-link'>About us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class='nav-link'>Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class='nav-link'>Contact</a></li>
            <li id="dropdown" class='nav-link'>More</li>
        </ul>
       
    </nav>
    
    
    <header id="header">
    </header>
    
    
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    
    
</html>
```

Comment: Your nav has still 60px when clicked once. After the second click it's height is set to 325px.

Comment: Because the `.height` starts off at `""`, irrespective of the CSS.

Comment: Since you're going back to the original height, do this: `if(get.nav.style.height === '') {
                get.nav.style.height = '325px';
            } else {
                get.nav.style.height = '';
            }`
Or better, use a class instead of setting CSS properties directly on the element.

Comment: @Blauharley yes but its strange that the code ignores the first if statement right?

Comment: @BarryB I just saw it. Nevetheless it has 60px after the first click

Comment: @squint thank you! thats it. Thanks for learning! i didnt know that the .height starts of at " "

Comment: @BarryB: You're welcome. Yes, the `.style` of an element gives only what was set directly. You can use `window.getComputedStyle` to include any CSS styling, but it's really just simpler to do what I show above, or again to use classes instead.

Comment: @squint classes is a good idea indeed! thanks dude! very helpful. Now i understand the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `get.nav.getBoundingClientRect().height` to get the initial height value.

So in this case you can compare "real" value with your points (325 or 60).

As **@squint** mentioned in comments, you can't rely on style's height property. Try to go with `getBoundingClientRect` ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect)) instead.

Comment: glad I could help :)